# Sending char pointer with UDP in C

Tags: c, udp

I have a struct that I am sending to a UDP socket:

```
typedef struct
{
    char field_id;
    short field_length;
    char* field;
} field_t, *field_p;
```

I am able to read the `field_id` and `field_length` once received on the UDP server-side, however the pointer to `field` is invalid as expected.

What is the best method to properly send and receive a dynamic char*?

I have a basic solution using `memcpy` on the client side:

```
char* data = 
    (char*)malloc(sizeof(field_t) + (sizeof(char) *  strlen(my_field->field)));
memcpy(data, my_field, sizeof(field_t));
memcpy(data+sizeof(field_t), my_field->field, strlen(my_field->field) + 1);
```

And on the server side:

```
field_p data = (field_p)buffer;
field_string = (char*)buffer+sizeof(field_t);
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this or is this the only way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You of course cannot send a pointer over a socket - get rid of the `char* field;` member. Instead, just append id and size pair with the data itself. Use [`writev(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) or [`sendmsg(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendmsg) to avoid moving data around from buffer to buffer.

Watch out for [structure member alignment and padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and number [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: A slight bit of pedantry: you can send a pointer over a socket, but unless the other end of the socket is the same program, or something sharing the same memory space, it won't do you any good.

Comment: Yo can send yo mama over a socket :)

Answer (score 0):

[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is your friend.

Related Links:

[SO-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c)

[SO-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652193/serialize-and-send-a-data-structure-using-boost)

Answer (score 0):

Define your structure as:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t  field_id;
    uint16_t field_length;
    char     field[0]; // note: in C99 you could use char field[];
} field_t, *field_p;
```

Then, text buffer will immediately follow your structure. Just remember a few tricks:

```
// initialize structure
field_t *
field_init (uint8_t id, uint16_t len, const char *txt)
{
    field_t *f = malloc (sizeof (field_t + len)); // note "+ len";
    f->field_id  = id;
    f->field_length = len;
    memcpy (f->field, txt, len);
    return f;
}

// send structure
int
field_send (field_t *f, int fd)
{
    return write (fd, f, sizeof (*f) + f->field_length); // note "+ f->field_length"
}
```

I don't think it's standard, though. However, most compilers (GCC && MSVC) should support this. If your compiler does not support zero-sized array, you can use one-element char array - just remember to subtract extra one byte when calculating packet size.