# Serializing an object with Boost for Named Pipes in c++

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, named-pipes

I am attempting to serialize some EEG data from a command line application using the Boost library for the serialization and sending that serialized data over a named pipe to a user interface Form built in Visual Studio C++ 2010.

From the boost library tutorial I am able to serialize my data structure, and,  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase

from this tutorial on Win32 named pipes, I can construct pipes and send text between applications.
http://avid-insight.co.uk/joomla/component/k2/item/589-introduction-to-win32-named-pipes-cpp?tmpl=component&print=1

The boost library tutorial serializes for a text file:

```
std::ofstream ofs("filename");

// create class instance
const gps_position g(35, 59, 24.567f);

// save data to archive
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    // write class instance to archive
    oa << g;
    // archive and stream closed when destructors are called
}
```

I want to know what do I need to serialize to in order to send my data structure over a named pipe? The IOstream c++ library seems to always need a file to stream to/from?http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

I don't want o serialize to a file and I am not sure what to serialize to? I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what I need to serialize to and it would be great if you could tell me whether another boost command will be required other than boost::archive::**text_oarchive** , as I have been unable to find an alternative.

Thank you for your time! It is really appreciated!

(This question has been asked before: [Serialize and send a data structure using Boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652193/serialize-and-send-a-data-structure-using-boost) , but the person was told not to use boost as for his simple data structure boost would have too much overhead, so it really is still floating.)

Comment: Serialize in std::stringstream and then send std::stringstream::str()?

Comment: Try attaching the named pipe handle to an ofstrem/ifstream like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/475853/775806).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ForEveR, very simple, don't know how I missed it! :) The solution in context with the two tutorials posted above:

```
    const EEG_Info g(35, 59, 24.567f);
std::stringstream MyStringStream ;
boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(MyStringStream);
    // write class instance to archive
    oa << g;
// This call blocks until a client process reads all the data

string strData;
strData = MyStringStream.str(); 


DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
result = WriteFile(
    pipe, // handle to our outbound pipe
    strData.c_str(), // data to send
    strData.length(), // length of data to send (bytes)
    &numBytesWritten, // will store actual amount of data sent
    NULL // not using overlapped IO
);
```