# Writing complex C++ objects to file

Tags: c++, file, serialization

I have a C++ objects that looks like this

```
class myClass
{
    vector<OtherClass*> otherClassVector;
    AnotherClass* anotherClassObj;
    // A few other primitive types and functions
}
```

What is the best way to store this to disk and read it back programmatically?
Will using fstream read/write in binary mode work? Or should I use boost serialization? And why?
I don't require the stored file to be human readable.

Comment: look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c

Comment: fstream read/write in binary mode will work, as long as you don't think that you can write the whole object out in one go. You will have to write the code yourself to write each individual subobject plus vector sizes and everything else. It's to avoid this kind of tedious and error prone work that you should think about using boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `boost::serialization` is simply, than write your own serializer. If OtherClass is concrete type (not base) - serialize by read/write is simple, for vector - just save size and than array (if your myClass has no non-POD types) and then store element on which points anotheClassObj pointer...

Answer (score 3):

You can serialize objects with `ofstream f("filename", std::ios::binary);` only if those objects are POD-types.

Anything else needs to be handled manually. For a simple example, if the object contains any pointers, the addresses of those will be saved, not the data they point at.

For more complex types, you will have to either serialize them completely manually (write a class or function that will save all the POD data from the class and do something tricky with all the "special" data)), or use boost serialization.

Comment: what does containing pointers have to do with the object being POD or not?

Comment: @Grizzly, nothing, it's just an example of something that needs to be handled manually.

Comment: I realize that, but if I didn't know I would think there was a correlation from the way your answer is formulated

Comment: @Grizzly, yea you have a point... I rephrased it a little, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [C++_Middleware Writer](http://webebenezer.net) may be of interest.  It has [some advantages](http://webebenezer.net/comparison.html) over other approaches.