# How to read from a file in a load/save function?

Tags: c++, file, function

I know the title is a little confusing, but I don't know how to explain it.

```
void save (POINT pt)
    {
    ofstream save;
    save.open("coords.txt", ios::trunc);

    if (save.is_open())
    {
        save << pt.x << endl;
        save << pt.y;

        save.close();

        system("CLS");

        cout << "Save successful\n\n\n\n";

        system("PAUSE");
    }

    else
    {
        system("CLS");

        cout << "Error: Could not save\n\n\n\n";

        system("PAUSE");
    }
    }

    int load ( )
    {
        ifstream load;
        load.open("coords.txt", ifstream::in);

        if (load.is_open())
        {

        }
    }
```

I want to read the `POINT` from the save function inside of the load function. I tried

```
 if (load.is_open())
    {
        load >> pt.x;
        load >> pt.y;
    }
```

but `pt.x` and `pt.y` are undefined. I'm not very good at this, but I 'm trying to understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm unsure of what you're asking

Comment: So, what I'm doing is an auto clicker. I have a set coordinate in the program already but I added a calibration option where the user could input their own coordinates to fit a different screen resolution. I want to save the coordinate into a file and when they reopen the program I want to be able to read the file and use the coordinates as a default.

Comment: it seems like your problem is that you haven't declared a POINT structure in the load function.

Comment: But when I declare a POINT structure in the load function it fails because it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: What do you mean it fails? Have you looked at the answer I provided?

Comment: Nevermind, I apologize. When I initialized the new POINT structure it gave me back the coordinates I saved in the save function. I guess I just didn't understand why it worked that way.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain (standard) `iostream` objects for serialization/deserialization can lead to a lot of pain.

I suggest you to use some higher-level serialization library like `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` and `boost::archive::binary_iarchive` ([link to the doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)).

It is quite easy to use, avoir you a lot of issues, and gives you the opportunity to discover a very useful C++ library.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (load.is_open())
{
while(load.good())    
{
   getline(load,point);
   pt.x=line;
   getline(load,point);
   pt.y=line;
    }
else{
 file open failed.
}
```

assuming `pt.x` and `pt.y` as `string`. if they are `integer` then you need to convert the `point` to `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just need to declare pt? Or is it a member?

```
int load ( )
    {
        POINT pt;
        ifstream load;
        load.open("coords.txt", ifstream::in);

        if (load.is_open())
        {
            load >> pt.x;
            load >> pt.y;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous poster suggestes, plain `iostream` might not be the best choice...

albeit in this case, your problem seems to be lack of definition of `POINT pt` in the scope of `load()` functions.

Perhaps create a singleton responsible for settings?

```
class MySettings
{
private:
    POINT m_pt;
public:
    static MySettings* instance()
    {
         static MySettings settings;
         return &settings;
    }

    int save(POINT pt) {...}
    POINT load() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer is quite obvious, you need to add a `POINT` argument to `load`:

```
/* The & symbol gives you back the points when the function has returned */
/* Alternatively, more conventionally, you may use a pointer. */

int load (POINT & pt){
    ifstream load;

    load.open("coords.txt", ifstream::in);

    if (!load.is_open()){
        cerr << "File couldn't be opened" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    load >> pt.x;
    load >> pt.y;

    load.close();

    return 0;
}
```

After this function has returned, the pt argument contains the points you're looking for. You would call it like this:

```
POINT points;
load (points);
```