# write object data to txt file in c++

Tags: c++

i have created a class as shown below

```
    class Registry
     {
        char m_name[20];
        char m_type[20];
        unsigned int m_value;
      public:
             Registry(char *name,char *type,int value=0)
             {
                     m_name=name;
                     m_type=type;
                     m_value=value;                       
             }
```

now i created a object as shown below

```
    Registry r1("alex","rez_sz",10);
```

now i want this object to be stored in a text file....plz tell me how to store the object in text file...?

Comment: [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is what you're looking for.

Comment: that class won't compile without `};` you might look up object serialization on google

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c

Comment: Why use char* instead of std::string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is called *serialization*. One option is to write your own method that simply writes every value in the object to disk in a format of your own choosing, or you can use an external libray. You can find more information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin solution to write an object into a file. You have to serialize it.

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c) if you want more informations.

Answer (score 0):

What are you asking about is object serialization:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

I recommend reading this question
[Is it possible to serialize and deserialize a class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234724/is-it-possible-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-class-in-c)

and this page
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html