# What is the usual way of sending data across network?

Tags: c++, sockets

In C#, I use Binary Serialization to send information across the Stream. This is quite simple as all you do is create a class, serialize it and then deserialize it on the receiving end.

My question is, how can I do something similar in C++? All of the network examples I've seen sends a const char * like;

```
send("LOGIN");
```

If I wish to send a string and an integer over network, must I really go to the trouble of converting both to a string, putting a command in front of it, and then sending;

```
[PSEUDO-CODE]
send("COMMAND|" + tostring(someInteger) + "|" + someString);
```

Then on the receiving end, splitting this string and parsing? I imagine this would get complicated when I have a vector stored and I want to send this over the network.

What can I do?

Comment: Can't help with the transport, but to send objects, just serialise them to XML or better still JSON- that way you just need to send strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c (c++) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: Why not using tcp/ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) formats and libraries (but outside of the C++11 standard).

In practice, your question is operating system specific. I guess you use Linux or some Posix system.

I usually recommend serializing in a [textual format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) (easier to debug). Then consider formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) (or [YAML](http://yaml.org/), perhaps even [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) -but I don't recommend it since it is too complex- etc...) and use libraries like [JSONCPP](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/)

<sup>In most cases (but not always!), network transport -milliseconds- is much slower than serialization computing -microseconds- so the textual serialization overhead does not matter much</sup>

If you want some binary serialization (beware of [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues), consider perhaps [libs11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/), [XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), etc... See also [htonl(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/htonl.3.html)

Always *document* (and keep up to date the documentation) your [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communications_protocol).

For transport, use TCP/IP (or something above it, e.g. [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http), [0MQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98MQ), etc...). On Linux and Posix, see [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) and read some [tutorial on BSD sockets](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Sockets.html).

You may need to code some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or use an existing event loop framework, `libev`, `libevent`, *Glib* from GTK, *QtCore* from Qt, etc etc...)

See also [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/), [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) etc

Comment: "*I guess you use Linux or some Posix system*.." Linux is a longshot given the "*In C#, I use Binary Serialization*"

Comment: some people do use mono

Answer (score 1):

C# has Windows Communication Foundation(WCF) using which you can serialise & send messages across the network. It also handles underlying transport over HTTP, TCP or HTTPS. You can learn more about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms731079%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Google's protobuf library actually isn't bad