# C++ returning memory address and not value

Tags: c++, pointers, char, operator-overloading, ostream

I used a `**char` pointer/array to store a list of char values.

I have a method to store the values, but my method to retrieve these values have not been as successful.

This is my method that sets the values...

```
char **names; 
char *input_name;
int studentNameSize;

void Students::setStudentNames() 
{
    names = new char*[studentNameSize]; 
    for(int i=0; i<studentNameSize; i++)
    {
        names[i] = new char[60];
        cout << "Input name" << i << ": \n";
        cin >> input_name;
        strcpy(names[i],input_name);
        cout << names[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

This is my method and it only return the memory size and not the actual values. It returns `0x(size of the array`, i.e. `0x03` instead of something like `Bob; Charles; Mike`

```
const char** Students::getStudentNames()
{
    for(int i=0; i<this->studentNameSize; i++)
    {
        return this->names[i];
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm new to C++ and I need some assistance with the `friend ostream& operator<<`. Basically I know how to output to file now but I don't get how to use the `friend ostream& operator<<` method of doing it. I have something like this but I am really lost as to how I can output to file this way.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& ostream, const Students& students)
{
    os << students.getStudentNames();
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that `return`, well... ***returns*** from the function? If you are returning in a for loop, then you won't "return an array". Instead, you will return the first element and then the function will have finished execution. Also, in C++, use `std::vector<std::string>` for an array of strings.

Comment: Your question seems to suddenly change into a different question halfway through. What's going on?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what's going on is that apparently OP has no idea about the fundamentals of the language, consequently he is unable to usefully and clearly state his problem/question.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: You're getting ruder and ruder as the weeks go by.

Answer (score 2):

This right here is not going to do what you expect.  A return statement instantly leaves the function, so the first time this loop is met, it will return.

So effectively, this code:

```
const char** Students::getStudentNames()
{
    for(int i=0; i<this->studentNameSize; i++)
    {
        return this->names[i];
    }
}
```

Really means this:

```
const char** Students::getStudentNames()
{
    return this->names[0];
}
```

I believe what you really want to do is this:

```
const char** Students::getStudentNames()
{
    return this->names;
}
```

This bit of code returns the entirety of the `this->names` variable, which according to the function name `getStudentNames` is what it does anyway.

As for the serialization part of your question, your code is mostly correct in that instance.  It should look like this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Students& students)
{
    os << students.getStudentNames();
    return os;
}
```

And to deserialize:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Students& students)
{
    is >> students.names;
    return is;
}
```

Note that these methods of serialization, when using more complex objects, are much more susceptible to data corruption.  Here is some [further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c) for you.

Hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I modify your code so that it can return all the values of names? Would I have to store it some array or something. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out as I am new to C++

Comment: @user4167396 Sure thing, give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: @user4167396 There you go!

Comment: Thank you for your generosity. It means a lot to me, and I appreciate people like you who are willing to help me out, unlike some users who decide to get rude

Comment: @user4167396 Hey no problem man.  Don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you, that way other users from google can find the answer easier!

Comment: Thanks! As for the ostream operator, how do I use it to store my information into a txt file? Sorry, I am new to C++

Comment: @user4167396 I haven't had to do this in a couple years, give me a few minutes to remember how to do it, then I'll update my answer!

Comment: Thanks phantom. It means a lot to me

Comment: @user4167396 There you go.

Comment: I am getting this error `invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'` for your `getStudentNames()` method

Comment: @user4167396 if `this->names` is of type `char**`, just change your method to `char** Students::getStudentNames()` e.g. remove the `const` keyword.

Comment: Thanks Phantom. My `setStudentNames()` method is crashing my program, and I don't even know why :(

Comment: @user4167396 That's kind of out of the scope of the original question...your question has been answered mark it as accepted and create a new question.