# Allocating a user defined struct in shared memory with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I am trying to use `boost::interprocess` to allocate a very simple data structure in shared memory but I cannot quite figure out how to use the [boost interprocess allocators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/interprocess/allocator.html) to perform the memory allocations/deallocations within the shared memory segment which I allocate as follows

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMem");
mSharedMemory = std::make_unique<managed_shared_memory>(
    open_or_create, "MySharedMem", 65536);
```

I previously asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204104/sharing-a-custom-struct-using-boostinterprocess) but unfortunately I never got any answers. `MyStruct` below is essentially an array with a length field indicating the size of the array.  For now I have a simple length field but I will add some other constructor arguments later (bool's and other simple types).

In order to allocate this in the shared memory segment, I know I have to do something with allocators but I cannot find a similar example where I have a user defined type containing an array/pointer field.

```
    using MyType = struct MyType {
        explicit MyType(const size_t aSize)
            : mSize(aSize)
            , mpData(new char[aSize])
        {}

        ~MyType() {
            delete[]mpData;
        }
        size_t mSize;
        char * mpData;
    };

    using MyTypeAllocator = boost::interprocess::allocator<MyType,
        boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;

    // Initialize the shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    MyTypeAllocator alloc(mSharedMemory->get_segment_manager());
```

Comment: You need to teach `MyType` to also use an allocator rather than use `operator new`.

Comment: @T.C.  Thanks, any pointers on how I might do that? I've been searching for some simple example.  Its very easy with ints or uint32_t's as they are trivial, the problem with a struct with a pointer field is that the sizeof() is funny as it does not account for the size of the allocated bytes that also need to be stored.  I think this has something to do with nodes in the boost::interprocess world but I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do manual allocation. If you want a contiguous allocation of `aSize` elements of type `char`, that's what C++ has `std::vector` for.

Best of all, `std::vector` already knows how to use another allocator, so there is really no reason not to use it:

```
template <typename Alloc>
struct MyType {
    explicit MyType(size_t aSize, Alloc alloc = {}) : mData(aSize, alloc) {}

  private:
    std::vector<char, Alloc> mData;
};
```

Now to play well with standard library construct/scoped allocators, you might want to define the `allocator_type` nested type:

```
    using allocator_type = Alloc; // typename Alloc::template rebind<char>::other;
```

That's all. Just use it as any standard library type that has an allocator:

```
int main() {
    using namespace Shared;

    Shared::remove("MySharedMem");
    auto memory = Segment(create_only, "MySharedMem", 65536);

    using A = Alloc<char>;
    A alloc(memory.get_segment_manager());

    auto* data = memory.find_or_construct<MyType<A>>("data")(1024, memory.get_segment_manager());

    return data? 0 : 255;
}
```

I created a few convenience typedefs in the `Shared` namespace, for maintainability. Here's the full sample

### Full Sample

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90d7f8bbbc7b5386)</kbd>** ¹

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <vector>

template <typename Alloc>
struct MyType {
    using allocator_type = typename Alloc::template rebind<char>::other;

    explicit MyType(size_t aSize, Alloc alloc = {}) : mData(aSize, alloc) {}

  private:
    std::vector<char, Alloc> mData;
};

namespace Shared {
    namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

    using Segment = bip::managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> 
        using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Manager>;

    void remove(char const* name) { bip::shared_memory_object::remove(name); }

    using bip::create_only;
}

int main() {
    using namespace Shared;

    Shared::remove("MySharedMem");
    auto memory = Segment(create_only, "MySharedMem", 65536);

    using A = Alloc<char>;
    A alloc(memory.get_segment_manager());

    auto* data = memory.find_or_construct<MyType<A>>("data")(1024, memory.get_segment_manager());

    return data? 0 : 255;
}
```

---

¹ For Coliru uses managed mapped file because shared memory is not supported there

Comment: great answer as always, but would it be possible to add some additional simple members to MyType and have them stored in shared memory also, e.g. MyType taking a bool, uint64_t and possibly a string in addition to the aSize parameter.   These first two extra parameters have trivial allocators and there are good examples on shm_string types with custom allocators, I’m not sure how the MyType would be correctly saved and subsequently restored from shared memory.

Comment: Of course. POD data is never an issue in [shared] memory

Comment: there is a lot going on under the covers of your example program, I am trying to understand it first: "using allocator_type = typename Alloc::template rebind<char>::other" is very confusing and doesn't seem necessary (I think rebind has something to do with node allocations within a container, I commented out the line of code in VS and it still worked), Also, using A = Alloc<int> - what is the <int> parameter used for?  It seems that this expands to boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>.

Comment: Then we construct alloc with 'memory.get_segment_manager()' - which I thought should be an 'int' argument, however get_segment_manager() returns a 'segment_manager *' which is not exactly an int.

Comment: About the nested typedef, I specifically said what I added it for. Feel free to disregard.

Comment: The int was a bit of leftover, I though I had removed that.

Comment: apologies for the nested typedef - my bad!  You were clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157499/discussion-between-sehe-and-johnco3).