# Writing linked list to txt file(Saving process)

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

```
struct node
{
string info;
struct node *next;
}*start, *last;

long nodecount=0;
class teditor
{
public:
    node* create_node(string);
    void insert_pos();
    void save();
    void display();
    void delete_pos();
    teditor() 
    {
        start = NULL;
    }
 };
 node *teditor::create_node(string value)
{
struct node *temp, *s;
temp = new(struct node); 
if (temp == NULL)
{
    cout<<"Memory not allocated "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    temp->info = value;
    temp->next = NULL;     
    return temp;
 }
}
void teditor::save()
{   
struct node *info;
ofstream listfile;
listfile.open("example.txt",ios::out|ios::app |ios::binary) ;
node *temp;
temp=start;
if(!listfile){
 cout<<"\nError";
 }
 else{
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    listfile.write((char*)(temp),sizeof(nodecount));
    temp=temp->next;
}
}   
listfile.close();
cout<<"\n\n\n\t\tLink list has been saved in file example.txt in current folder.";
cout<<"\n\n\t\tPress a key to continue ... ";getch();
}
void teditor::insert_pos()
{
string value; int counter;
int pos;
cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
cin>>value;
struct node *temp, *s, *ptr;
temp = create_node(value);
cout<<"Enter the postion at which node to be inserted: ";
cin>>pos;
nodecount++;
int i;
s = start;
while (s != NULL)
{
    s = s->next; counter++;
}
if (pos == 1)
{
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = temp;
        start->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr = start;
        start = temp;
        start->next = ptr;
    }
}
else if (pos > 1 )
{
    s = start;
    for (i = 1; i < pos; i++)
    {
        ptr = s;
        s = s->next;
    }
    ptr->next = temp;
    temp->next = s;
 }
else
{
    cout<<"Positon out of range"<<endl;
}
}

void teditor::display() 
{
/*
Need to merge as a string and show to display just in one line like writing
why cannot save health because of application saving pointers.
*/
node *temp;
temp=start;
cout<<"\n\n\n";
while(temp)
{
    cout<<"\t\t\t"<<temp->info;
    temp=temp->next;
}
cout<<"\n\n\t\t "<<nodecount<<" records displayed ,Press a key to continue.....";getch();
}
void teditor::delete_pos()
{
int pos, i, counter = 0;
if (start == NULL)
{
    cout<<"List is empty"<<endl;
    return;
}
cout<<"Enter the position of value to be deleted: ";
cin>>pos;
struct node *s, *ptr;
s = start;
if (pos == 1)
{
    start = s->next;
}
else
{
    while (s != NULL)
    {
        s = s->next;  
    }
    if (pos > 0 && pos <= counter)
    {
        s = start;
        for (i = 1;i < pos;i++)
        {
            ptr = s;
            s = s->next;
        }
        ptr->next = s->next;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Position out of range"<<endl;
    }
    free(s);
}cout<<s<<" Element Deleted"<<endl;nodecount--;
 cout<<"There is left "<<nodecount<<" nodes"<<endl; 

  }
```

Hi,guys!I have problem while I trying to save my linked list to txt.Everytime I tryin and txt gave me a chinese writing.Teacher also said I need to merged with string or I need to give node to string that application can easily save that string line.Maybe because of I 'm trying to write `node *temp`.Anybody know how can I solve my problem?After other processes it will be copy,cut,paste and replace with nodes.

Comment: Where is your `main()`? Couldn't reproduce your problem.`

Comment: in main() `teditor sl; start = NULL; and I used switch:case that I can call easily sl.save();`

Comment: Where do you "start" your linked list `node`? `start` should not be NULL, it should, somewhere, be `= *node;`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
listfile.write((char*)(temp),sizeof(nodecount));
```

to

```
listfile << temp->info;
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not want to write the pointer `temp` into your files, you wanted the `info` that is inside the `node` that `temp` is pointing at. Then why you are writing `temp` instead of writing the `info`? YOu could do that "through" your pointer `temp`, right?

The below will do the above for you:

```
listfile << temp->info;
```

Comment: but still show same thing Am I did mistake while I insert string to linked list.?

Comment: @BahadırSoybakış thats the only thing I can think of if you're still getting garbage. try to include the code that populates the list in the question

Comment: @bahad Post a [MCVE] or you would need to _step-into_ your code statement by statement to watch your logic and the values of every variable.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you have a serialization problem. You want text in the file. But you are simply dumping memory to the file.

```
listfile.write((char*)(temp),sizeof(nodecount));
```

just writes the raw memory of a node.

Ask yourself - what should the text file look like? What do you expect it to look like in an editor. THen you have to write code to do that.

YOu need to do

```
listfile << temp->info
```

How do you want to save the next and prior. Maybe it is implicit in the ordering. SO this is all you need. Maybe you need line numbers ans to say `next=4, prior=14`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c) shows that serialization. I think as you say I need to define some variable to relate.@pm100

Answer (score -2):

Your problem will be solved after doing these steps:

1. Right click on the project name, go to properties
2. In general -> project defaults -> character set
3. Choose not set