# std::copy char vector byte by byte

Tags: c++

How do I copy an `int` (or any other data type) byte-by-byte to a `vector<unsigned char>`?

```
int x = 10;
std::vector<unsigned char> byteArray(sizeof(int));
std::copy(byteArray.begin(), byteArray.end(), x); // how do I use x here?
```

If not possible with `std::copy`, can it be done with `memcpy` or any other technique?

Comment: `vector<unsigned char> byteArray[sizeof(int)]` is an array of `std::vectors`

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to initialize it with `sizeof(int)` elements

Comment: try memcpy(byteArray.data(), &x, sizeof(int));

Comment: @Daniel wow, that worked. Thanks!

Comment: To confirm: are you attempting to decompose an `int` into a vector of bytes that represent its value? And if so, do you care about little endian vs. big endian representation?

Comment: @CraigYoung I don't care about the representation, I need to calculate a hash value based on it's bytes.

Comment: Then I expect you probably should care. Endianness is about the order of the bytes in an integer. Any hash that function that is not affected by the order of the bytes is a pretty weak hash.

Comment: I see your point. The hash I'm using is a non-cryptographic hash meant only for hash-based lookups. The issue is the data type can be any data type. That means I need to make separate byte conversions for int, long, char *, etc. which might not be worth the effort. Also, I'm not looking to make the code portable.

Comment: gotcha, since hashes will be internal, byte-order will be consistent within a system - whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Problem you are dealing with is called serialization.
Solution with memcpy is 'crude but effective' so if your project is small I think it is OK to use it. Otherwise I recommend looking at some solutions, for 
 example, provided in boost or Qt. This will provide you with generic interface for multiple data types.

[How do you serialize an object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c)