# C++ how to convert any class (custom) object to vector <unsigned char>

Tags: c++, serialization, variadic-templates

I have defined my own class :

```
class Rectangle {
  int width;
  int height;
};
```

I want to convert any such class object to `vector<unsigned char>`. I tried doing it for particular types, and then for any type:

```
template< typename T > std::vector< byte, sizeof(T) >  to_bytes( const T& object ) {
    std::vector< byte, sizeof(T) > bytes ;
    const byte* begin = reinterpret_cast< const byte* >(std::addressof(object)) ;
    const byte* end = begin + sizeof(T) ;
    std::copy( begin, end, std::begin(bytes) ) ;
    return bytes ;
}
```

But this is valid only for a particular `type` in C++. How can I convert my `Rectangle` class, or any user defined class for that matter to `vector<unsigned char>` ?

Comment: Do you know what `std::vector< byte, sizeof(T) >` is?

Comment: `std::vector< byte, sizeof(T) >` are you sure?

Comment: `std::vector`'s second parameter is its allocator. I don't know what you're trying to do

Comment: It will create a vector of `sizeof(T)` bytes ? I am not sure. I am getting errors in compilation. Sorry I am new to C++

Comment: @user3636955, *absolutely no*. I recommend reading some documentation before trying to use it.

Comment: I am referring here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/155821/

Comment: "It will create a vector of sizeof(T) bytes ?" No it will not. What makes you think so? I recommend getting a C++ book.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you serialize an object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c)

Comment: @user3636955, it is written there explicitly, `std::array`. `std::array` and `std::vector` are different.

Comment: 1. The page you link doesn't mention std::vector at all. 2. cplusplus.com is not recommended as a beginner's resource, it's full of errors.

Comment: Can you help me on how I can modify the code to obtain `std::vector<byte>` ? Instead of `std::array`

Comment: @n.m. can you give me a reference to how I can convert any type to vector<unsigned char> ? I am new to c++ and would like to understand that.

Comment: There's no generic method. Why do you want to?

Comment: I want to store it in a data structure that needs `std::vector<unsigned char>`. I am using this trie : https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/develop/libdevcore/TrieDB.h , the `insert` function. But I would like to serialize any class to `std::vector<unsigned char>` basically.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by making a user defined type conversion in Rectangle class:

```
explicit operator vector<unsigned char>() const {
// Do something here
}
```

Hope this helps.