# Writing objects to hard disk files in C++

Tags: c++, serialization

I want to write an instance of a class that includes different data types into hard disk and read it whenever I need. 
I used the below code to do this. The problem is that whenever I save the object into a file, it creates a file on the folder but it is just size of 1 KB. Also when I open the file from the same function that saves the file, I can read variables in the class, but when I move the read section to another function and open the file from there, variables cannot be read. How can I fix the problem? Thanks in advance.

Write to a file:

```
stream.open("configuration/KMeansModel.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
stream.write((char *)& kmeans, sizeof(kmeans));
stream.close();
```

Read from the file:

```
KMeans::KMeans kmeans_(umapFeatureLabel_);
stream_.open("configuration/KMeansModel.bin", std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);
stream_.read((char *)& kmeans_, sizeof(kmeans_));
stream_.close();
```

Class definition:

```
class KMeans
{
private:
    int m_K;
    int m_iters;
    int m_dimensions;
    int m_total_features;
    std::vector<Cluster> m_clusters;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_umapFeatureLabel;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<std::vector<long double>>> m_umapClusterFeatureList;

    int getNearestClusterId(Feature feature);

public:
    KMeans::KMeans::KMeans();
    KMeans(std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& umapFeatureLabel);
    void run(std::vector<Feature>& allFeatures);
    void predict(Feature feature);
    void updateKMeans(std::vector<Feature>& allNewFeaturesRead);
    std::string getLabelOfFeature(std::string feature);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you serialize an object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c)

Comment: Print `sizeof(KMeans)`  and compare that number to how many bytes there actually are in your file.

Comment: Not a bug, but your default constructor declaration has two more `KMeans::` than it needs, and your declaration of `kmeans_`  one more.

Comment: @molbdnilo prints 216 kb, writes 1 kb file

Comment: 216 k?! I get 152 *bytes*, which would probably use 1 kb of disk space..

Comment: I think the problem is that std::vector and other containers do not store memory locally but use dynamic memory allocation.  You need to not just write the value of the pointer but the data it points to.  So you need a serialization library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The bad news:

Your file saving code uses function `sizeof`. Your data structure includes vector and map objects.

For example, as far as `sizeof` is concerned, a `std::vector` object takes 16 bytes, absolutely regardless of the number of elements. That's 8 bytes for the element count, plus 8 bytes for the pointer to the actual elements, assuming a 64 bits machine.

Say your vector has 100 elements, 8 bytes per element, and the elements are stored starting at memory address 424000. The `write` method will dutifully store into the file a) the number 100 and b) the number 424000; but it will make absolutely no attempt to save into the file memory locations from 424000 to 424800. For it has no way to know that 424000 is a pointer; that's just a number.

Hence, the file does not contain the information that is necessary to restore the vector state.

As mentioned in the comments above, the subject of saving complex pointer-based data structures into simple byte arrays for the purpose of file storage or network transmission is known as *serialization* or *marshalling/unmarshalling*.

It is a non obvious subject of its own, in the same way as sorting algorithms or matrix multiplication are non obvious subjects. It would probably take you a lot of time to come up with a properly debugged solution of your own, a solution that takes care of maintaining consistency between saving and restoring code, etc ...

### The good news:

Serialization is a non-obvious subject, but it is also an old, well-known subject. So instead of painfully coming up with your own solution, you can rely on existing, publicly available code.

In similar fashion, the only situations where you would have to come up with your own matrix multiplication code is when:

1. you're doing it purely for fun and/or self-training
2. you are writing a PhD thesis on matrix multiplication
3. you're paid to write linear algebra code

Other than these, you would probably rely on say existing [LAPACK](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/) code.

Regarding serialization, as hinted to by Botje in the comments above, the Boost web site provides a C++ serialization library, along with a suitable [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html).

### Sample code:

I am providing below a small code sample using the Boost library. A simple guinea pig object contains an integer value, a string and a map. Of course, I am shamelessly borrowing from the Boost tutorial.

We need to include a couple of header files:

```
#include  <map>
#include  <fstream>
#include  <iostream>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
```

The object class, which pretends to store some token geographical info:

```
class CapitalMap
{
public:
    CapitalMap(const std::string& myName, int myVersion) :
        _name(myName), _version(myVersion)
    {};

    CapitalMap() = default;  // seems required by serialization

    inline void add(const std::string&  country, const std::string& city)
    { _cmap[country] = city; }

    void fdump(std::ostream& fh);

private:
    std::string                         _name;
    int                                 _version;
    std::map<std::string, std::string>  _cmap;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;  // ALLOW FOR FILE ARCHIVAL
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & _name;
        ar & _version; // mind the name conflict with plain "version" argument
        ar & _cmap;
    }
};
```

A small debugging utility function:

```
void CapitalMap::fdump(std::ostream&  ofh)    // text dumping utility for debug
{
    ofh << "CapitalMap  name = \"" << _name << "\"  version = " <<
           _version << '\n';
    for (const auto&  pair : _cmap) {
        auto  country = pair.first;  auto  city = pair.second;
        ofh << city << " is the capital of " << country << '\n';
    }
}
```

Code to create the object, save it on disk, and (implicitely) deallocate it:

```
void buildAndSaveCapitalMap (const std::string&  archiveName,
                             const std::string&  mapName,
                             int                 version)
{
    CapitalMap  euroCapitals(mapName, version);

    euroCapitals.add("Germany", "Berlin");
    euroCapitals.add("France",  "Paris");
    euroCapitals.add("Spain",   "Madrid");

    euroCapitals.fdump(std::cout);  // just for checking purposes

    // save data to archive file:

    std::ofstream                  ofs(archiveName);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive  oa(ofs);
    oa << euroCapitals;

    // ofstream connexion closed automatically here
    // archive object deleted here    - because going out of scope
    // CapitalMap object deleted here - because going out of scope
}
```

Small main program to create the file and then restore the object state from that file:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string archiveName{"capitals.dat"};

    std::cout << std::endl;
    buildAndSaveCapitalMap(archiveName, "EuroCapitals", 42);

    // go restore our CapitalMap object to its original state:

    CapitalMap                     cm;  // object created in its default state
    std::ifstream                  ifs(archiveName);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive  inAr(ifs);

    inAr >> cm;           // read back object ...
    std::cout << std::endl;
    cm.fdump(std::cout);  // check that it's actually back and in good shape ...
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem of maintaining consistency between saving and restoring code is brilliantly solved by altering the meaning of operator “&” according to the direction of travel.

Minor problems along the way:

1. on a Linux distro, you need to get packages: boost, boost-devel, boost-serialization
2. it seems the object class needs to have a default constructor
3. you need to include files such as “boost/serialization/map.hpp” manually

### Program execution:

```
$ g++  serialw00.cpp  -lboost_serialization  -o ./serialw00.x
$ ./serialw00.x

CapitalMap  name = "EuroCapitals"  version = 42
Paris is the capital of France
Berlin is the capital of Germany
Madrid is the capital of Spain

CapitalMap  name = "EuroCapitals"  version = 42
Paris is the capital of France
Berlin is the capital of Germany
Madrid is the capital of Spain

$
```

More details here: [SO_q_523872](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523872/how-do-you-serialize-an-object-in-c)